# A div to follow higher z-index div

Tags: javascript, css

Sorry for the title, it's very hard to explain.
On [that page](http://formation.financement-creditplus.fr/) I have a menu with sub menus, if you go on "Nos formations" button you'll see a long sub menu that goes below the backgroud image which make it less readable.

So this is what I have (simplified):

```
<div id="backgroundimage"  style="z-index:1 ..."></div>    
<div id="menu" style="z-index:5">
    <div id="submenu">
         <div id="button1">
         <div id="button2">
    </div>
</div>
```

My idea was to put an opaque div under each button but at a z-index of 0 for them to be under the background image so their will never hide the it. But as the buttons are contained in another div it seems impossible.

So is there a simple solution ? (if possible avoiding javascript)

Thanks

Comment: why not just add a little more padding underneath the central banner?  just  my humble opinion but the overall look is a bit cluttered

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to limit the height of the submenu and make it scrolling:

```
.smLongHeight{
   max-height: 200px;
   over-flow: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you go with **:last-child** parameter to set the last button background opacity to 1. Will help you for now, but I would prefer to use Javascript to make the last buttons more opaque.

With CSS, I think you can only use something like:

```
#menu #submenu div:last-child{ background: rgba(255,255,255,1); }
```